# AddType application/x-httpd-php .html stopped working

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I have the following line in .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

And it used to work for years to treat html pages as php, however recently I noticed it is not working anymore, except only in the homepage (`example.com`), and not even at the same page (`example.com/index.html`)

I tried now to add the following to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.6.conf` and restarted apache, but still it didn't work.  Also tried other suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php), but still no luck.

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Any idea what could have happened?  Or how to fix that?

Comment: Something like this suddenly stopping working is typical of a server upgrade; but by the sounds of it, this is your own server and nothing has changed? Or have you changed the version of PHP being used? What do you mean by: "except only in the homepage (`example.com`), **and not even at the same page** (`example.com/index.html`)"?

Comment: I thought the problem was for encoding or particular files, but the `index.html` is the same in the above note, so how is it working on the domain name, but not it's `index` file, which is the exact same!  (Of course along with not working in the whole site).

Comment: Ah, you're saying `example.com/` works (ie. loads `index.html` and processes as PHP), but a direct request to `example.com/index.html` does not? And you don't have a `index.php` in there as well? `example.com/` results in mod_dir loading `index.html` via an internal subrequest - that is the difference (although I don't know why that would make a difference).

Comment: Yes,  don't have an `index.php`, it's just `index.html`.

Comment: Do you have many `.html` files? May not be what you had in mind, but my preference would be to use the correct file extension for these files and use URL-rewriting to rewrite the `.html` request to the underlying filesystem (ie. to `.php`). This is more reliable cross server and altogether more flexible IMO.

Comment: That's an idea right, but I just wanted to understand the issue before doing something like that..

Answer (score 2):

Find out your handler by creating a PHP file with following contents

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HANDLER']; ?>
```

When opened from browser, it will return the handler name for php. Then replace your current htaccess code with correct handler. For example, if your output is `application/x-httpd-php5`, then your htaccess will look like this:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.html$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375772/2703813

Comment: This PHP script, when run on my server, provides an empty output. What does that mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can find out your handler by checking phpinfo as well.